# text file to textbox silverlight

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, text

I feel this is super simple but Windows form load up my text files nice and neatly but Silverlight seems to do several things differently

I just want to have text from a pre-made text file load into a text box on Silverlight.

This is what I have.

In the Public Class:

```
Dim streamer As IO.StreamReader
Dim Inblines As String()=IO.File.ReadLines("C:\users\tcook\desktop\Ultipro\DEFlvl\Inbox.txt")

Private Sub Main_SelectedItemChanged( THE USUAL)Handles Main.SelectedItemChanged

If Main.SelectedItem.ToString = "Inbox" Then
        txtb1.Text = Inblines
    End If
```

Gives me the 1-dimensional array of String cannot be converted to String.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Change from using the ReadLines Method to ReadAllText:

```
Dim Inblines As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\users\tcook\desktop\Ultipro\DEFlvl\Inbox.txt")
```

As you can tell you also change Inblines from a String array to just a String.

Comment: Dim Inblines As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\users\tcook\desktop\Ultipro\DEFlvl\Inbox.txt") still throws an error. If I "comment" this line, the program works